# Smart Highlighting in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

For the life of me, I cannot find the setting that allows changes to Smart Highlighting in Qt Creator. See the image below for an example. When I click the `start` variable, Qt Creator puts a box around other occurrences of the variable. Where is the setting to change the background color of these highlights?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can change it:

`Tools > Options > Text editor > Occurences`

Currently selected option (I changed color to dark red or sililar):

[image: Occurences background color]

Comment: Thank you. I could have sworn I tried changing that before, but changing it to a bright green made it more noticeable. Thank you!

Comment: What's make this extra confusing is that pressing "Apply" does not update the color of the current selection. I had to close the preferences, deselect and select the variable again before the change showed.

Comment: unable to change occurrences color scheme . Arrow button next to "Background" text is disabled